# Can I safely discard the Fallen Transponder after obtaining Outbreak Perfected?

Tags: destiny-2

It takes up space in the quest inventory, which as all Guardians know, counts towards your max bounty limit. In any case, I've already completed the normal Zero Hour mission, so is it safe to discard it? Or will I need to hold on to it to still have access to the Heroic Zero Hour mission? If I do lose it, can I reobtain it without having to do those intermediary quest steps again?

Comment: The new season which starts today may fix this by separating out Quests and Bounties. "Added categories to the Quests screen." in https://www.bungie.net/en/Explore/Detail/News/48827

Comment: Nope, that just categorizes the type of quests, but not the actual quest/bounty system

Comment: We'll find out in a short while! As the patchnotes are up https://www.bungie.net/en/Explore/Detail/Update/48838

Comment: @DavidYell Nope, didn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having carried this quest around for a while, I thought I'd experiment and see what happened.

I have completed the Zero Hour mission and got my Outbreak Perfected. I still had the Fallen Transponder for the Heroic version.

I deleted the quest and was still able to zone into both the regular and heroic missions.

The regular version I zoned into the Farm and interacted with the Fallen NPC in the basement.

The heroic version I launcher from the Director on Earth.